# Angular Table row-span and col-span based on typescript data object

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

[image: ow]

[Stackblitz Demo of code You can edit for reference.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arma3g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

As shown in above image, Table is generated using dynamica data coming from class file data-object. and based on row-span and col-span data-object value in class table generated with those settings. I have done col-span of table based on data-object settings.

My Question is that, see on second Row and column `Thursday31` starts col-span by three, which is `Thrusday Friday and Saturday` col-spans. after col-spans done remaining is `sunday`. But `ngFor` starts from where condition breaks and display remaining more data which is `Friday saturday Sunday`. I want only to display remaining value only after col-span done, means result should me `only sunday` after col-span from `thrusday31`.

**typescript data.ts**

```
  weeks = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Firday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

 mySentences = [
   {"Id":"abc","Name":"Cus1","day":2,"begin":3,"total":2},
   {"Id":"bcf","Name":"Cus2","day":4,"begin":2,"total":3},
   {"Id":"uuu","Name":"Cus3","day":7,"begin":5,"total":4}, 
 ].sort((a,b) => a.begin < b.begin ? -1 : 1 );
```

In `mySentences...

```
begin = starts form row,
day = starts from column,
total = col-span value.
```

**HTML is**

```
 <div class="col-md-12" >
    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-hover hidder" id="report">
        <!-- Header -->
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%;"></td>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Monday</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Tuesday</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Wednesday</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Thursday</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Friday</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Satuday</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Sunday</th>
        </tr>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; let i = index;">
        <tr>
          <td> {{item}} </td>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let week of weeks; let j = index">

          <ng-container *ngFor="let sm of mySentences">

            <ng-container *ngIf="sm.begin === i+1 ; ">


            <td *ngIf="sm.day === j+1; else weekDay"  [attr.colspan]= "sm.total" >
               {{week + j+1 }}
            </td>
            </ng-container>
              <ng-template #weekDay>
              <td>  {{week}} </td>
              </ng-template>       
            </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </tr>

     <ng-template #elseTmp>
       <td style="width: 10%;">row: {{i+1}}</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">col: 2</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">col: 3</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">col: 4</td>
            <td  style="width: 10%;">col: 5</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">col: 6</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">col: 7</td>
            <td style="width: 10%;">col: 8</td>
     </ng-template>

</ng-container>
    </table>
</div>
```

And also, remaining row display normal, remaining means not in `mySentence` array of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the additional iteration through `mySentences`. You need a method that returns whether or not to render the `<td>` element based on the current row (i) and current week (j) index. I.e. Don't render the `<td>` when the current index is between the start and end of a span on the same row.

Something like this for example:

```
public showDay(begin: number, day: number) {
  return !this.mySentences.some(
    m => m.begin === begin && day > m.day && day <= m.day + m.total - 1
  );
}
```

I've attempted to modify your Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfsrc1

(Bear in mind that I've made some assumptions on what data you want displayed in the cells)

Comment: Thank you, for your simplification of the question.. Answer is working properly, Though can you show how to put `showDay()` logic using in Custome-pipe..?